# How can I fill a column entry in Postgres with the value from the previous row if no value exists?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the following schema, where `tstamp` is epoch:

```
Table "public.count_history"
 Column |  Type  | Modifiers 
--------+--------+-----------
 data   | text   | not null
 tstamp | bigint | not null
 count  | bigint | not null
Indexes:
    "count_history_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (data, tstamp)
```

And I have the following custom function that helps me group counts into "buckets":

```
                                                                     List of functions
 Schema |   Name   | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  | Security | Volatility | Owner | Language |        Source code         | Description 
--------+----------+------------------+---------------------+--------+----------+------------+-------+----------+----------------------------+-------------
 public | ts_round | bigint           | bigint, bigint      | normal | invoker  | volatile   | foo   | sql      |                           +| 
        |          |                  |                     |        |          |            |       |          |   SELECT ($2 * ($1 / $2));+| 
        |          |                  |                     |        |          |            |       |          |                            |
```

I have the following query that gets me the max count value for each "bucket" of time, which is 24 hours:

```
SELECT data, ts_round(tstamp, 86400) AS tstamp, max(count) AS count FROM count_history GROUP BY 2, 3;
```

There's a chance a bucket of time may be empty, in which case a row won't be returned for that bucket of time. How could I go about still returning a row for that bucket of time with the `count` value from the previous row?

Comment: What is more than one continuous bucket be empty?  Then taking the previous row would not work.  One general solution to your problem is to use a calendar table which contains entries for each bucket of time (or possibly points for each original timestamp).  Then join to this calendar table to make sure each bucket appears.

Comment: If more than one consecutive bucket of time was empty, then the first empty one would get the value of the previous non-empty bucket. After that each consecutive empty one would get the previous, which would be the same for all of them. Can you provide an example of your calendar table idea?

Comment: A calendar table is just a table containing all the dates for the time periods of interest.  Join to it to get your desired result.

Comment: Also, there could be more than one "bucket" per day for different values of `data`. What should be returned if the next day has no values?

Comment: Since the grouping is by data and time, an empty bucket for a particular data value would get filled with the previous count value associated with the data value.